# how can i capture data from one class and pass it around all classes

Tags: java

i have a multi class program, with each class having its own GUI, my task is to capture details from a class called dataInput and the data must be captured into variables of a class called studentRecords, i must capture about 10 records comprised of name, surname, student number and tests from 1-4, i have a class called RecordsMenu which have Buttons that call the different classes, for example, when i click dataInput button it calls the DataInput class, in the datainput class i must capture data into records class, then i must go back to recordsMenu screen, from there! when i click for example, the display Button , i must be able to see the data i captured, the problem i have is that, when ever i go back to the main screen , all the data i captured get lost and it print nulls when i test whether it captured or not, i will appreciate any kind of help, my code is below.this must be done with out using files, thank you
    [here is the picture of the main screen of my application][1]

```
    enter code here

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6JyI.jpg
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


import javax.swing.*;

public class InputDetails extends JPanel
{
    JLabel title,name,surname,studentno,tests,t1,t2,t3,t4;
    JTextField nametxf,surnametxf,studentnotxf,t1txf,t2txf,t3txf,t4txf;
    JButton submit,home;
    JPanel buttons, mainPanel, labels;

    public InputDetails()
    {
           // title
           title = new JLabel("Records Menu",SwingConstants.CENTER); 
           title.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
           Font newLabelFont =new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,70);
           title.setFont(newLabelFont); 
           // buttons and actions
           submit = new JButton("Submit");
           submit.addActionListener(new Handler());
           home = new JButton("Home");
           home.addActionListener(new Handler());
           //labels
           name = new JLabel("Name");
           surname = new JLabel("Surname");
           studentno= new JLabel("Student Number");
           tests = new JLabel("Tests");
           // tests
           t1 = new JLabel("Test 1");
           t2 = new JLabel("Test 2");
           t3 = new JLabel("Test 3");
           t4 = new JLabel("Test 4");

           //textfields
           nametxf = new JTextField(10);
           surnametxf = new JTextField(10);
           studentnotxf = new JTextField(10);
           t1txf= new JTextField(10);
           t2txf= new JTextField(10);
           t3txf= new JTextField(10);
           t4txf= new JTextField(10);

            buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
            buttons.add(submit);
            buttons.add(home);
        // fields
            labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7,1,5,5));  
            labels.add(name);
            labels.add(nametxf);
            labels.add(surname);
            labels.add(surnametxf);
            labels.add(studentno);
            labels.add(studentnotxf);
            labels.add(t1);
            labels.add(t1txf);
            labels.add(t2);
            labels.add(t2txf);
            labels.add(t3);
            labels.add(t3txf);
            labels.add(t4);
            labels.add(t4txf);
            // 
            mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
            mainPanel.add(title,BorderLayout.NORTH);
            mainPanel.add(labels,BorderLayout.WEST);
            mainPanel.add( buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(mainPanel);


    }
    class Handler implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
        {

            if(click.getSource()==home)
            {

                // back to main view    
                mainPanel.setVisible(false);
                add(new RecordsMenu());
            }
            else if(click.getSource()==submit)
            {

                String name,surname,studentno;
                int test1,test2,test3,test4;

                name = nametxf.getText(); 
                surname = surnametxf.getText();
                studentno=studentnotxf.getText();
                test1 =Integer.parseInt(t1txf.getText());
                test2 = Integer.parseInt(t2txf.getText());
                test3 = Integer.parseInt(t3txf.getText());
                test4 = Integer.parseInt(t4txf.getText());
                StudentRecords records = new StudentRecords(name,surname,studentno,test1,test2,test3,test4);






            }


        }





    }




}
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class StudentRecords {

     String name , Surname, studentno;
     int test1,test2,test3,test4;
     FileWriter records;
     PrintWriter out;


      public StudentRecords(String Name, String Surname,String StudentNo,int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4)
      {

          setName(Name);  
          setSurname(Surname);
          setStudentno(StudentNo);
          setTest1(t1);
          setTest2(t2);
          setTest3(t3);
          setTest4(t4);

        //  saveRecords();  


      }




     public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSurname() {
        return Surname;
    }
    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        Surname = surname;
    }
    public String getStudentno() {
        return studentno;
    }
    public void setStudentno(String studentno) {
        this.studentno = studentno;
    }
    public int getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }
    public void setTest1(int test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }
    public int getTest2() {
        return test2;
    }
    public void setTest2(int test2) {
        this.test2 = test2;
    }
    public int getTest3() {
        return test3;
    }
    public void setTest3(int test3) {
        this.test3 = test3;
    }
    public int getTest4() {
        return test4;
    }
    public void setTest4(int test4) {
        this.test4 = test4;
    }










}
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ReadFile extends JPanel{

private JButton read,back;  
private JTextArea desplay;
private JLabel title;
private JPanel mainpanel, buttons;
String record,student1,student2,student3,student4,student5,student6,student7,student8,student9,student10;
public  ReadFile()
{

    // title
 title = new JLabel("Read File Contents",SwingConstants.CENTER);
 Font newLabelFont =new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30);
 title.setFont(newLabelFont); 

 // textarea


  desplay = new JTextArea();


 // buttons
  read = new JButton("Open");
  read.addActionListener(new Handler());
  back = new JButton("back to main");
  back.addActionListener(new Handler());
 // panel
  buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,5,5));
  buttons.add(read);
  buttons.add(back);

   mainpanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
   mainpanel.add(title,BorderLayout.NORTH);
   mainpanel.add(desplay,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   mainpanel.add(buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    add(mainpanel);


}
class Handler implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {


        if(click.getSource()==read)
        {

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            Scanner input = null;
            if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {


            File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {   
            input = new Scanner(selectedFile);  
            while(input.hasNextLine())
            {
                record = input.nextLine();
                desplay.append(record);
                desplay.append("\n");


            }



            }catch(IOException fileerror) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have an error");


            }   



            }





        }
        else if(click.getSource()==back)
        {

      mainpanel.setVisible(false);
        add(new RecordsMenu()); 
        }




    }




}




}
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Search extends JPanel
{
    DisplayDetails d = new DisplayDetails();
    JLabel title,stdn;
    JTextField studentno;
    JPanel mainp,details,buttons;
    JButton search,home;
    Scanner input;
    File records;
    String key;
    String line;
    boolean wordfound = false;
    public Search()
    {

        // title
         title = new JLabel("Search a Student",SwingConstants.CENTER);
         Font newLabelFont =new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30);
         title.setFont(newLabelFont); 
         stdn = new JLabel("Student Number");
         studentno = new JTextField(10);
    //   
         search = new JButton("Search");
         search.addActionListener(new Handler());
         home = new JButton("Home");
         mainp = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         details = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
         details.add(stdn);
         details.add(studentno);

         buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
         home.addActionListener(new Handler());
         buttons.add(search);
         buttons.add(home);

         mainp.add(title,BorderLayout.NORTH);
         mainp.add(details,BorderLayout.WEST);
         mainp.add(buttons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         add(mainp);
    }
    class Handler implements ActionListener
    {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent button)
        {
            if(button.getSource()==search)
            {   
                // define the key
               key = studentno.getText();   
                if(key.matches("^2\\d{8}"))
                {
                     File file =new File("StudentRecords.txt");
                     Scanner in;
                     try {

                         in = new Scanner(file);

                         while(in.hasNextLine())
                         {
                            line=in.nextLine();


                            if((line.contains(key))) {
                                wordfound=true;
                                  break;



                                  }





                         }
                           if((wordfound)) {
                              System.out.println(line); 
                              mainp.setVisible(false);
                              add(d);
                              d.display.setText(line);
                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"found");  

                              }
                           else 
                           {

                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"not found"); 



                           }


                         in.close();
                     } catch(IOException e) {

                     }







                }   
                else if(!(key.matches("^2\\d{8}")))
                {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"incorrect student number"); 


                }










        }
            else if(button.getSource()==home)
            {


                mainp.setVisible(false);
                add(new RecordsMenu());

            }

        }
    }
    // methods

       public void RecordFOund()
        {



        }
       public void notFound()
       {




       }



            }




import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame
{
    public  Frame()
    {

       setSize(500,400);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new RecordsMenu());
      // add(new Search());
       setVisible(true);





    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your code and compress it by removing superfluous empty lines and code that is not relevant to your problem, your code is very hard to read as it is now.

Comment: You don't store data in *classes*, you store data in *objects*.  A class is the definition of an object, like a blueprint.  When you're on a "main screen" and you click a button to open an "edit screen" for a particular record, presumably you are building an instance of that object.  Upon saving and leaving the "edit screen" that instance needs to be kept somewhere.  In a database, in an in-memory list of some kind, or even just returned back to the "main screen" for it to manage the object.  But you need to keep your object instances somewhere in order to use them later.

Comment: how do i keep this data, and retrieve it as i click the buttons in the main screen, plz help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Comment: @OnkeO'RealDeepNkqwili: There's far too much code here to meaningfully answer that.  Start with a much simpler example.  Create a program with a main form that's always open and a second form for editing a record.  Have a private variable on the main form to store your value.  When you open the second form, populate it with that value.  When you save the second form and close it, update the value on the main form.  Keeping this as simple as possible, when you try to do that where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

try this
In the getter methods of the StudentRecords Class make them  {return this.variable;}
as an example in the public int getTest1(){return this.test1;}